# Custom SharePoint 2010 WCF Service - How to set MaxReceivedMessageSize parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have developped a custom WCF Web Service within a SharePoint 2010 Visual Studio empty project.

My web service is working well. The problem is related to the size of the request I can send to this web service. I have realized that is something around 300Kb. If I go bigger than that, the service/client is sending me an exception.

I've looked around on the web and see that the MaxReceivedMessageSize setting may be my solution. I've tried using a FeatureActivated method to set this information using this kind of request:

```
// increase maximum size of requests to this web service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx
SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
contentService.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = -1;
SPWcfServiceSettings csomWcfSettings = new SPWcfServiceSettings();
csomWcfSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760; // 10MB
contentService.WcfServiceSettings["PT-SP-P2S-DocumentCreator.svc"] = csomWcfSettings;
contentService.Update(); // access denied thrown here!
```

With that code, I have an Access denied (I'm actually the Site Collection Administrator).

I also know that this parameter may be set in the app.config of web service host but, in SharePoint, where to I need to change this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make this change in the web.config file of the Web Application in which the feature is activated. SharePoint provides APIs to make web.config changes. In fact, using APIs to make changes to your web.config is preferred option because SharePoint uses Timer Job and makes same updates to all Web Front End servers in your environment. There are 2 ways to make changes to web.config as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460914.aspx

In your case, since you want to make the change only when your feature is activated, you would take the API approach as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx